# Deleting user profile registry key based on profile name with Batch file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, registry

I am attempting to write a batch script to delete a registry key for a user profile. The user profile will always have the same name, but the key is different for every computer and increments each time the username is created, even though the previous one was deleted.

I'm guessing that it would require some type of for loop to identify the key value for the ProfileImagePath as C:\Users\Username.

I know wildcards don't work so reg delete 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-*' /f won't work.

I'm aware of some PS scripts that can do this, but I would like to keep this in a batch file.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your situation/environment.  Are you running the script as admin while the user is logged in, and for that reason you are going about it this way?  Or are you trying to make changes to a user that isn't logged in?  In the former, you can find who is logged on via `\\HKU\`, but in the latter you need to load their hive files on the hard drive into HKU and then make changes.  Please describe your situation so we can better help you.

Comment: If you are running a version of Windows with`wmic` (like Windows 10), you could use something like `for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe useraccount where "name=username_of_account'" get sid /format:csv') do set "_userSID=%%g"`

Comment: The comment above would capture the exact SID of the user in question. Replace username_of_account with their exact username.

Comment: You need to better define your intention. Simply deleting a registry key is not the correct way to remove a user account / profile from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single line example of the methodology I'd suggest, (which will not become obsolete when `WMIC.exe` is removed from Windows 11).

```bash
@For /F "EOL= Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /S /F "C:\Users\Username" /D /E 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "S-1-5-21-"') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Delete "%%G" /V "ProfileImagePath" /F 1>NUL 2>&1
```

*Please take account of [my commented advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396699/deleting-user-profile-registry-key-based-on-profile-name-with-batch-file#comment127906477_72396699) too.*